# Broadleaf Running core and Admin

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I am using Broadleaf for one of my project. I want to use only the admin and core module. But when I run the project I have this error " Table 'broadleaf.blc_system_property' doesn't exist". Is it possible to run the demosite without the site module. I mean just core and admin.

Thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the site application is started with this set in the 'site' application, in site/src/main/resources/runtime-properties/development.properties:

`blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create-drop`

With this setting, the following happens when you start up the site application:

1. Application start
2. All database tables are dropped
3. All database tables are created
4. The load SQL in core/src/main/resources/sql is executed
5. Application finishes starting up

--- Application runs for however long it runs; do cart operations, register customers, etc

5. Shut down application
6. All database tables are dropped
7. Application is done shutting down

In the admin application, this is set in admin/src/main/resources/runtime-properties/development.properties:

`blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=none`

With that setting, this is what happens:

1. Application Start
2. Nothing happens with the database
3. Application finishes starting up

--- Run for however long

3. Shut down application
4. Application is done shutting down

Basically, to fix your issue you want to change it such that when you start up the admin application it also creates tables and runs the import sql. I recommend changing this to create. So in admin/src/main/resources/runtime-properties/development.properties change it to this instead:

`blPU.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=create`

With that setting, this is how the application will behave:

1. Application start
2. All database tables are dropped
3. All database tables are created
4. The load SQL in core/src/main/resources/sql is executed
5. Application finishes starting up

--- Application runs for however long it runs; do cart operations, register customers, etc

5. Shut down application
6. Application is done shutting down

Answer (score 0):

check your database, seems like this table is not there. On Unix like systems the table names are case sensitive so if your table was created in upper case, that would be the reason why broadleaf can't find it.

Yes and it is possible to run the admin without the site. To do that, just deploy the admin.war. Core is a separate maven module that is used by both the admin and site and is packaged as a jar in the war files.

Comment: It's not the problem of database naming. Because  the system has already create four tables (blc_bank_account_payment,blc_credit_card_payment,blc_gift_card_payment)

Comment: 4 tables are not enough, it should be around 183 tables in total

Comment: The problem is solved. It cames  from my database setup. I have 164 tables. May be Because I exclude the CMS module. I got another error  **[ERROR] 23:20:47 SqlExceptionHelper - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(255)) is null or sandboximp2_.ARCHIVED<>'Y')' at line 1**